# LARAVEL Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, apache

this is my set up for the projects:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.basiclaravel.website
    ServerAlias www.basiclaravel.website
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Nancy\Documents\Projects\Backend\Laravel_10_Projects\BasicLaravelWebsite/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

the link http://www.basiclaravel.website/ is working, 
http://www.basiclaravel.website/about or http://www.basiclaravel.website/contacts does not work, I am getting error message:
Not Found
The requested URL /contact was not found on this server.

Route set up:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

 Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});
```

home, about, contact are in the same folder views.

if I set up about or contact for www.basiclaravel.website it is displayed.

Any idea what might be issue?

Another issue came up after I installed composer require

```
"laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

any of my css or bootstrap code is working, the page is clean in HTML only
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the pages via index.php, for example http://www.basiclaravel.website/index.php/contact for the contact page.

If that works, either you don't have `mod_rewrite` installed and/or enabled as per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#web-server-configuration), or your Apache config is setup to prevent overrides by the Laravel `.htaccess` file.

Update your virtual host as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName basiclaravel.website
    ServerAlias www.basiclaravel.website
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Nancy/Documents/Projects/Backend/Laravel_10_Projects/BasicLaravelWebsite/public"

    <Directory "C:/Users/Nancy/Documents/Projects/Backend/Laravel_10_Projects/BasicLaravelWebsite">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache for the settings to take effect, and the .htaccess should now work.

Comment: Thanks Dave, links are working, I did not change  AllowOverride All before. CSS is also fixed with href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}